# java.lang.ArithmeticException on Facebook Android Library

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have an AritmeticException error on [Facebook Audience Network Android Library](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/). I use version of 4.25.0 and get following errors via Google Play Developer Console. (I never saw any crash or error on my phone)

```
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.c.b.h$2.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.c.b.h$2.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.h.q.b (Unknown Source)
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.h.q.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.h$1.run (Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5951)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1400)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

**Error distribution by app version, android version and device** [image]

I use same codes by months so it could be a bug of version 4.25.0. Do you have any idea how to fix this and what is that?

Answer (score 2):

It is happening on interstitial ads and you can fix it by disabling AutoPlay Video option. 
To disable Auto Play video, go to 
[developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) choose your app. On the sidebar **Audience Network** > **Ad Spaces** . Select your interstitial ad place, click on **Edit** button and then click on **Show Advanced Option**. Below **media types header** switch check from *autoplay video* to *Click to play Video & Images* . Save and quit. 
This solved all my pain.

[Screeshot of editing screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwxIk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to fix it by downgrading from version 4.25.0 to version 4.23.0 of the SDK:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.23.0'
```

This is probably a bug in the newer version. Hopefully it gets fixed soon.